# How to incorporate standard security forms and logic into many projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have got a standard security package using own controllers and views and other classes 
(for example Authorization filters) in asp.net MVC.

I will need to incorporate the same into multiple projects .

What would be the best approach for incorporating these -I can copy the controllers and views and other classes into each project -I can make library but unsure how to handle controllers/views

Comment: If you have many separate web applications, do you really want the standard views to exist at multiple URLs? Why not have a single site for the security forms, and have the other projects reference this other site?

Comment: I cannot refer to a common security site as the applications are deployed in various places. It is something like a library that I need -but with views and controllers I am not sure what is the best way to make into libraray